# How to override setup and cleanup methods in spark map function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scalding

Suppose there is following map reduce job

**Mapper**:

setup() initializes some state

map() add data to state, no output

cleanup() ouput state to context

**Reducer**:

aggregare all states into one output

How such job could be implemented in spark?

Additional question: how such job could be implemented in scalding?
I'm looking for example wich somehow makes the method overloadings...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark `map` doesn't provide an equivalent of Hadoop `setup` and `cleanup`. It assumes that each call is independent and side effect free.

The closest equivalent you can get is to put required logic inside `mapPartitions` or `mapPartitionsWithIndex` with simplified template:

```
rdd.mapPartitions { iter => {
   ... // initalize state
   val result = ??? // compute result for iter
   ... // perform cleanup
   ... // return results as an Iterator[U]
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

A standard approach to setup in scala would be to use use a lazy val:

```
lazy val someSetupState = { .... }
data.map { x =>
  useState(someSetupState, x)
  ...
```

The above works as long as the `someSetupState` can be instantiated on the tasks (i.e. it does not use some local disk of the submitting node). This does not address cleanup. For cleanup, scalding has a method:

```
    TypedPipe[T]#onComplete(fn: () => Unit): TypedPipe[T]
```

which is run on each task at the end. Similar to the mapping example, you can do a shutdown:

```
    data.map { x =>
      useState(someSetupState, x)
    }
    .onComplete { () =>
      someSetupState.shutdown()
    }
```

I don't know the equivalent for spark.

Comment: Thank a lot, I'll definitely try it, But how to output the "someSetupState" from the .onComplete() and not .map()?